# Cannot be cast to com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to build an android studio plugin by using IntelliJ SDK api's, and getting below exception, and not able to find any clue on its resolution:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker cannot be cast to com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker.getInstance(GradleInvoker.java:83)
    at com.accenture.codecoverage.plugin.android.action.UpdateReportOnSonar$1$1.run(UpdateReportOnSonar.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:85)
    at com.accenture.codecoverage.plugin.android.action.UpdateReportOnSonar$1.run(UpdateReportOnSonar.java:56)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:934)
    at com.accenture.codecoverage.plugin.android.action.UpdateReportOnSonar.actionPerformed(UpdateReportOnSonar.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:199)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$2(ActionMenuItem.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:920)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:295)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$300(TransactionGuardImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:843)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:675)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:391)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Getting above error on calling of below code line:

```
GradleInvoker.getInstance(mProject).executeTasks(gradleReportTasks);
```

Any one can give suggestion on this issue?

Thanks,
Sumeet.

Comment: Hi, anyone can help me on this issue...

Comment: Is there any one who is facing this type of error?

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the latest version of Android Studio (V2.3), and then check the latest android.jar file resides into Studio contents package, and   surprised that the API "com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker" removed from latest jar file, that means this API was deprecated into earlier version, and we were not aware about this, thats why we were getting strange error's, as mentioned into my this question.

You need to change your logic, and use another API's instead of GradleInvoker class, to achieve your results, but before that please keep your android studio with latest version V2.3

I hope it will help you...

Thanks,
Sumeet.